# can a user with 1 reputation in stackexchange comment on another user's question?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was looking at [THIS POST](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/infecting-a-vehicle-with-a-virus) and the first comment to the question caught my eye. The user who made it seems to have 1 reputation. [The comments help page](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says that you need 50 reputation to be able to comment on other user's post. How was this user able to post that comment?

Answer (score 3):

That user submitted the comment as an answer. It was flagged as not being an answer so I converted it to a comment on the question itself.

Comment: ... which is to say yes this situation can occur, but it requires either a moderator's intervention or somebody who commented and then lost a ton of rep (e.g., make comment, receive spam flag)